# SQL query with results based on current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I'm practicing on a php website with reservations. I've made three tabs on which I want to display reservations for today and for the coming week. 
So far I have this mysql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM users 
          LEFT JOIN reserveringen ON (users.userID = reserveringen.userID) 
        WHERE reserveringen.kamertype = 1 
          AND reserveringen.datum <= DATEADD(day,+7, GETDATE())";
```

but I it doesnt display any results

Edit:

I have made an if-else statement saying if there are results display them else echo a message saying "there are no reservations for the coming week". This is the query for showing all reservations and it runs just fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM users 
           LEFT JOIN reserveringen ON (users.userID = reserveringen.userID) 
        WHERE reserveringen.kamertype = 1`
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly isn't working? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: what database is this? HOW is "not working"?

Comment: Comments will more than likely not be answered to. Seeing that trend more and more lately and only responding to answers. *pfft*.

Comment: Thank you for giving us all a button to click on; the oen you've set to "ignore". You have a few high ranking members here who know their SQL quite well, yet nothing from you.

Comment: I have made an if-else statement saying if there are results display them else echo a message saying "there are no reservations for the coming week". 

This is the query for showing all reservations and it runs just fine: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN reserveringen ON (users.userID = reserveringen.userID) WHERE reserveringen.kamertype = 1`

Comment: ^ that...... says nothing about what is "not working". And I fear that some of those high ranking members have already lost interest and moved on. Anyway, you have been given an answer below, ask them. I have lost interest in this one myself, good luck again.

Comment: Well **show us the complete `if-else` statement**

Comment: THEN **Read The MYSQL Manual** There is **no** `DATEADD()` function in MYSQL, [its called `DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) and the parameters are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function name `DATEADD()` is a TransactSQL function. In MYSQL it is called `DATE_ADD()` and the parameters are different as well

So this is more likely to work

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM users 
          LEFT JOIN reserveringen ON (users.userID = reserveringen.userID) 
        WHERE reserveringen.kamertype = 1 
          AND reserveringen.datum <= DATE_ADD(CURRDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)";
```

Comment: Thanks this worked out for me. Can I do the same for today todays reservations like 'INTERVAL 1 DAY' or would that be different?

Comment: That seems like a good solution, check the [documentation for `DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) there are other intervals that you can use that may be useful to you. There is also `DATE_SUB()`